# TypeError: expected string or buffer log analyze

Tags: python

I'm trying to use my code to analyze the Apache log lines.
The log line is like this:

> 124.150.110.226 - - [26/Jun/2008:06:48:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 99 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080419 Ubuntu/8.04 (hardy) Firefox/2.0.0.14"

But I get the error message:

> ```
>     198 
>     199 def parse_apache(line):
> --> 200     log_split = log_regexp.match(line)
>     201     if not log_split:
>     202         print "Line didn't match!", line
> TypeError: expected string or buffer
> ```

My code is below:

```py
apache_log_headers = ['host', 'client_id', 'user_id',
    'datetime', 'method', 'request', 'http_proto', 
    'status', "size", 'referrer', 'user_agent']

log_format = (r'(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[(.*?)\] '
           r'"(\S+) (\S+) (\S+)" (\S+) (\S+) '
           r'"(.+)" "(.+)"')

log_regexp = re.compile(log_format)


def parse_apache(line):
    log_split = log_regexp.match(line)
    if not log_split:
        print "Line didn't match!", line
        return {}

    log_split = log_split.groups()

    result = dict(zip(apache_log_headers,log_split))
    result['status'] = int(result['status'])
    if result['size'].isdigit():
        result['size'] = int(result['size'])
    else:
        result['size'] = 0
    return result


def apache_lines(dir_name,file_type):
    return (parse_apache(line) for line in log_lines(dir_name,file_type))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for each_line in log_lines('/Users/SJX/Desktop/python project/python_learning','.log'):
        print each_line
        print parse_apache(each_line)

    print sum((each_line['size'] for each_line in apache_lines('/Users/SJX/Desktop/python project/python_learning','.log')
                                if each_line.get('status',0) == 200))
```

Comment: Print what's in <line> before <log_split = log_regexp.match(line)>

Comment: It's telling you that `line` is not what it expected to find. Check `log_lines()` to ensure it's not passing something other than a valid log line you expected.

Comment: print line. The output is a tuple,  which is about(path/apache_sample.log, one log line)    @lgor T.

Comment: what can I do? I can't solve the problem yet.

Comment: I solve my problem!!! Just log_split = log_regexp.match(line[1]). Thank you guys!!!!!